# Laravel 5.2 query to intersect results from first table and second table

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

Having the following pure MySQL SQL code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM products
LEFT OUTER JOIN rating_products
ON (products.id = rating_products.product_id)
WHERE rating_products.product_id IS NULL
```

Can someone guide how to rewrite code like this using the eloquent models, so that the soft delete will be generate and work nicely with Laravel.

The goal is to list only products not rated yet. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try as:

```
Product::leftJoin('rating_products', 'products.id', '=', 'rating_products.product_id')
        ->whereNull('rating_products.product_id')
        ->select('products.*')
        ->get()
```

Comment: will this add soft deletes in the query ?

Comment: I am sure but you can give it a shot.

Comment: How about many to many relations or something like that, by adding a property in the model its self, or this query is too complicated ?

Comment: NOPE, using relations are always encouraged. You can give it a try and if you stuck anywhere then SO is always here to help :)

Comment: So I should follow you code above, or by relations you mean adding properties in the models it self ?

Comment: By relations I mean to create [relation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships) between `products` and `rating_products` model. But for you can use above code.

Comment: Any tips how to ask properly the question related to Laravel's database manipulation :) ?

Comment: Nothing special just provide your DB schema and relations, someone obviously helps you.